# Running MediaMetadataRetriever getFrameAtIndex() with parallel coroutine workers is slower than running it with one coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to grab the frame from the video file using `MediaMetadataRetriever` with multiple parallel coroutine jobs, but the process takes more time comparing with running it with one coroutine. 
 I don't understand what is the problem, maybe `MediaMetadataRetriever` doesn't work for parallel execution and it blocks `getFrameAtIndex` method invocation for the same file?
or problem is in the parallel file access?
 My goal is to retrieve all bitmaps from ~1 second video file as fast as possible and thats why I decided to grab frames parallelly.

Here is time log with parallel and with one coroutine execution.

with one Coroutine

```
LOG_TAG: frame range 0..51  calculation for job_1 = 2206 ms
LOG_TAG_FINISHED: total grab time 2224
```

with 4 parallel coroutine

```
LOG_TAG: frame range 39..51  calculation for job_4 = 4484 ms
LOG_TAG: frame range 0..12   calculation for job_1 = 4524 ms
LOG_TAG: frame range 27..39  calculation for job_3 = 4634 ms
LOG_TAG: frame range 12..27  calculation for job_2 = 4716 ms
LOG_TAG_FINISHED: total grab time 4747
```

and the code

```
suspend fun startGrabbingFrames(src: String){

    val dataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    dataRetriever.setDataSource(src)
    val totalFrames =
        dataRetriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT)?.toLongOrNull() ?: 0L
    dataRetriever.release()

    val frameChunkSize = totalFrames / 4

    val offset1 = totalFrames - frameChunkSize * 2
    val offset2 = totalFrames - frameChunkSize

    val range1 = IntRange(0, frameChunkSize.toInt())
    val range2 = IntRange(frameChunkSize.toInt(), offset1.toInt())
    val range3 = IntRange(offset1.toInt(), offset2.toInt())
    val range4 = IntRange(offset2.toInt(), totalFrames.toInt()-1)
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async {  grabFrames(src,range1,"job_1") }
        val two = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async { grabFrames(src, range2,"job_2") }
        val three = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async { grabFrames(src, range3,"job_3") }
        val four = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async { grabFrames(src, range4,"job_4") }
        val frames1 = one.await()
        val frames2 = two.await()
        val frames3 = three.await()
        val frames4 = four.await()
    }
    println("LOG_TAG_FINISHED: total grab time $time")
}
```

and here is `grabFrames` method

```
private suspend fun grabFrames(src: String, range: IntRange, tag: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    retriever.setDataSource(src)
    val frames = ArrayList<Bitmap?>()
    measureTimeMillis {
        for (i in range) {
            val frame = retriever.getFrameAtIndex(i)
            frames.add(frame)
        }
        retriever.release()
    }.also {
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "frame range $range  calculation for $tag = ${it} ms")
    }
    frames
}
```

If I run it with only one coroutine it is almost 2 times faster, as shown in the log.

```
val one = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async {  grabFrames(src,IntRange(0,totalFrames-1),"job_1") }
val fullFrames = one.await()
```

Also tried to make 4 copy of that file and created 4 `MediaMetadataRetriever` object for each file and run 4 parallel job but the result was same.

Comment: Use one shared retriever, instead of one per task. Try to release the retriever in the last job. Calling release will reset the state of the retriever and on the next retrieval it has to reinitialize itself, that's why it takes more time.

Comment: you mean, I should use one global MediaRetreiver object for all jobs?

Comment: Yes, that will prevent the media retriever object to be released and created.

Comment: when using one mediaretriever object then it tooks much more time to finish the process
"total grab time 23133"